What is the condition of Geroch Monotonicity?
From what I understand, Geroch Monotonicity is typically discussed in the context of the Hawking mass or other quasi-local masses. For a two-dimensional surface $\Sigma$ in a spacetime with metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, the Hawking mass $m_H(\Sigma)$ can be defined as:
$$
m_H(\Sigma) = \sqrt{\frac{|\Sigma|}{16\pi}} \left(1 - \frac{1}{16\pi} \int_\Sigma H^2 \, dA \right)
$$
where $H$ is the mean curvature of $\Sigma$ and $|\Sigma|$ is the area of the surface. Geroch's idea is that under the appropriate conditions, particularly when the strong energy condition holds, this mass function should not decrease along a suitably chosen family of surfaces (typically taken to be null surfaces).
What are the precise conditions under which Geroch Monotonicity applies? Specifically, how do these conditions relate to the strong energy condition and the null convergence condition?
